# iOS programmatically aspect ratio constraint gets broken in UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to set an aspect ratio to an image inside a tableviewcell and it is getting broken because iOS can't accomplish accomplish constraints for width or height with decimals that are different from .5 or .0.

There is anyway to make that a constraint doesn't fail/break if it is close to its value, or it gets rounded to a value erasing the decimal?

I know that the problem is because of the decimal after many tries, I will show you with the following example:

With the following code

```
postImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 88.9).isActive = true
```

I get the following error:

```
    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036067b0 UIImageView:0x7fb76fe397e0.height == 88.9   (active)>
```

And the view view hierarchy the size of the image is 89

[image]

It happens to me when I set a height that is different from .5 or .0 it gets rounded to the nearest value .5 or .0 (If I set 88.6 it gets rounded to 88.5 throwing the error), but If I set any value that ends in .0 or .5 it works smooth!

(I know I can do it setting a lower priority but it can give me more unexpected behaviors)

(I am doing it programmatically, doing it through a Xib is not an option :) )

EDIT: Whole log:

```
    (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000facd20 UIImageView:0x7fc98362fe80.height == 86.9   (active)>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000facd70 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fc98362fe80]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc98362f940 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000face10 UIImageView:0x7fc98362fe80.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc98362f940.bottom - 8   (active)>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000fad680 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc98362f940.height == 95   (active)>"
    )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000facd20 UIImageView:0x7fc98362fe80.height == 86.9   (active)>
```

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to try and set a height of 88.9, nor should you want to. Because how does 88.9 points translate to pixels? let's say you're on a @2x device so one point would be 2 pixels high. then 88.9 points is 177.8 pixels. Which have to rounded of somehow anyway. 88.5 would become 177 pixels, which does make sense

Comment: @FilipD 88.9 was just an example, I am trying to set an aspect ratio and it changes in function of the width of the device when I set the aspect ratio 420/360 + insets it is when it gets broken

Comment: Can you show the whole error message Xcode gives you? There should be a list of constraints from which UIKit selects the one that it would break.

Comment: @pckill I have just edited it to add the whole log :)

Comment: Well the errors indeed show that the 95 - 8 don't equal the 86.9, so the layout engine is correct in trying to break one. 
But how is your cell able to determine the 95 content view height? That seems correct right? Maybe you don't need to have the imageview height constraint?

Comment: @FilipD he gets the height because of the image height, but he gets the closest possible

Comment: Set the priority to 999 instead of required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you *must* reduce the priority on your aspect-ratio constraint to avoid the broken constraint messages.

And, I think you're not-quite-correct about `nn.5` values working.

For example... With a `420:360` ratio:

setting the width of the view to `59` results in an auto-layout height calculation of

```
59.0 * 360.0 / 420.0 == 50.571428571428569
```

Auto-layout is not going to give you an actual view height of `50.571428571428569` ... it's going to round it to the nearest `.5` which is `50.5` and that is *less than* requested so you get the error.

With:

```
59.4 * 360.0 / 420.0 == 50.914285714285718
```

it rounds to `51`, which is *greater than* requested, and you **do not** get the error.

A few more examples:

```
58.5 * 360.0 / 420.0 == 50.142857142857146  // rounds down -- error
58.4 * 360.0 / 420.0 == 50.057142857142857  // rounds down -- error
58.3 * 360.0 / 420.0 == 49.971428571428568  // rounds up -- NO ERROR
```

Changing your aspect-ratio constraint to `Priority: 999` gives the same *sizing* results (rounds to the nearest `.5`) but does **not** throw the broken constraint error.

Since you will get the same actual size, changing the priority will simply allow auto-layout to "do the right thing" and shouldn't have any other effect on your layout.